# Coordinate system for map downloaded Digimap?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have download a 1: 25000 map from Digimap. It came as a tif file along with a tfw file. When I try to import the tif file as a raster layer, I get the following message: 'this layer appears to have no projection specification. By default, this layer will now have its projection set to that of the project, but you may override this by selecting a different projection below'. I then need to pick a projection.

The message suggests that the tif isnt georeferenced. How can I georeference the image to a WGS84 projection?

Comment: Try to Import into what application? DigiMap at 1:25k sounds like Ordnance Survey Explorer - http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/25k-raster/index.html which will be in OSGB36 (British National Grid) - they will need to be reprojected to WGS84 (slight flatten north/south will occur)